# how to set icon in web push notification using fcm in laravel 8

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging, laravel-8

**I have to set icon on notification but not working. please give me a solution for this issue. **

```
"notification" => [
                "title" => $request->title,
                "body" => $request->body,
                "icon"=>"https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1077/1077114.png"
             ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the **"icon"** property as member of **"data"**, as **"icon"** property vary from each technology (js, android, apns, etc.).

For JS, it can be URL, whereas for android it can be name of *"drawable resource"*.

```
"notification" => [
   "title" => $request->title,
   "body" => $request->body,
   "data" => [
      "icon"=>"https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1077/1077114.png"
   ]
]
```